# http images, fonts, etc aborted

Tags: html, http, get, abort

```
http://89.112.11.9/vol/
```

(Sorry for IP-address, I don't have any domain)

If you open this in Chrome you'll see that images do not load. In network tab of devtools it says that requests are aborted, but in FF it works.

Why? Where to look for issue?

Comment: that is really strange yes...

Comment: Check answer below found your fix.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work when I turn JavaScript off (Safari and Chrome). Maybe related to an included script?